# Get top users with user type by amount

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

i have tried to find top retailer and top distributor with below query.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount
   FROM transactions tm
     LEFT JOIN user_master um ON um.p_id = tm.user_id
   WHERE um.user_type = 'RT'
   GROUP BY ma_user_id
   ORDER BY total_amount DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS rt_topest,
  (SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount
   FROM transactions tm
     LEFT JOIN user_master um ON um.p_id = tm.user_id
   WHERE um.user_type = 'DT'
   GROUP BY ma_user_id
   ORDER BY total_amount DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS dt_topest
FROM transactions tm
WHERE tm.addedon >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(now()) - 1 DAY) AND
      tm.addedon <= now()
LIMIT 1;
```

**table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE user_master
(
  user_master_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  p_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  firstname VARCHAR(50),
  lastname VARCHAR(50),
  user_type CHAR(3) DEFAULT 'RT',
  addedon TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
);



CREATE TABLE transactions
(
  transaction_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT,
  amount DECIMAL(12,4),
  addedon TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  updatedon TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
);
```

how to find Top paid user in last month from below data as single row.

```
+----------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| transaction_id | user_id | amount   | addedon             |
+----------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|              1 |   18923 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-19 15:01:11 |
|              2 |   28766 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-18 18:01:11 |
|              3 |   28629 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-18 18:01:11 |
|              4 |   28699 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-18 18:01:11 |
|              5 |   28699 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-14 18:01:11 |
|              6 |   28699 | 100.0000 | 2021-12-10 18:01:11 |
|              7 |  129138 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-14 18:01:11 |
|              8 |   28627 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-17 18:01:11 |
|              9 |   29150 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-13 18:01:11 |
|             10 |   28619 | 100.0000 | 2021-12-31 18:01:11 |
|             12 |   28629 | 100.0000 | 2021-12-19 15:01:11 |
+----------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

**expected result**

```
+-----------+-----------+
| rt_topest | dt_topest |
+-----------+-----------+
|  300.0000 |  100.0000 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Sample Data

**transactions**

```
+----------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| transaction_id | user_id | amount   | addedon             |
+----------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|              1 |   18923 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-19 15:01:11 |
|              2 |   28766 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-18 18:01:11 |
|              3 |   28629 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-18 18:01:11 |
|              4 |   28699 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-18 18:01:11 |
|              5 |   28699 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-14 18:01:11 |
|              6 |   28699 | 100.0000 | 2021-12-10 18:01:11 |
|              7 |  129138 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-14 18:01:11 |
|              8 |   28627 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-17 18:01:11 |
|              9 |   29150 | 100.0000 | 2022-01-13 18:01:11 |
|             10 |   28619 | 100.0000 | 2021-12-31 18:01:11 |
|             12 |   28629 | 100.0000 | 2021-12-19 15:01:11 |
+----------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

**Sample Data users**

```
+----+-------+----------+-----------+
| id | p_id  | name     | user_type |
+----+-------+----------+-----------+
|  3 | 18923 | merchan1 | DT        |
|  4 | 28766 | merchan2 | RT        |
|  9 | 28699 | Kirti    | RT        |
| 19 | 28629 | test1    | DT        |
| 63 | 28627 | test2    | RT        |
+----+-------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. What is your actual question? Where is the problem? Do you have sample data? Please [edit] your question and add as many details as possible. Please also consider reading [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: See the tag I added.